# C# subscribe a function to System.Action that is subscribed to another System.Action: why does order matter?

Tags: c#, delegates, action

I have 3 classes, forming a tree. I'm using System.Actions to communicate events. But I'm confused why the order I subscribe matters. Check this pseudo code:

```
class Leaf
{
    public System.Action OnTrigger;
    public void Go()
    {
        if (OnTrigger != null)
            OnTrigger();
    }
}

class Chunk
{
    public System.Action OnTrigger;
    public Leaf leaf = null;
    public Chunk()
    {
        leaf = new Leaf();
    }
}

class Tree
{
    void Hello()
    {
        Debug.Log("Hello");
    }
    void World()
    {
        Debug.Log("World");
    }

    public Tree()
    {
        var chunk2 = new Chunk();
        chunk2.OnTrigger += Hello; // OK: will be called
        chunk2.leaf.OnTrigger += chunk2.OnTrigger;
        chunk2.OnTrigger += World; // NOT: not be called
        chunk2.leaf.Go();
    }
}
```

best regards,

Massa

Comment: Just as a side note the name you've given to your events is non-standard. It is normal to name the event that raises an event `OnTrigger`, but the event itself would normally be simply called `Trigger`. So, if your `Leaf` class the method `Go` should be `OnTrigger` and the event should be `Trigger` for them to be more like the standard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is relatively apparent from examining how delegates work and the MSIL that is created when you compile this. First lets note that `System.Action` is a [`System.Delegate`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/delegate.cs,0dd8585ba1833ad7) which has the `ICloneable` interface.

When you compile this program, here is pretty much what you get:

```
  IL_0015:  newobj     instance void [mscorlib]System.Action::.ctor(object,
                                                                    native int)
  IL_001a:  call       class [mscorlib]System.Delegate [mscorlib]System.Delegate::Combine(class [mscorlib]System.Delegate,
                                                                                          class [mscorlib]System.Delegate)
  IL_001f:  castclass  [mscorlib]System.Action
  IL_0024:  stfld      class [mscorlib]System.Action ConsoleTests.Program6/Chunk::OnTrigger
  IL_0029:  ldloc.0
  IL_002a:  ldfld      class ConsoleTests.Program6/Leaf ConsoleTests.Program6/Chunk::leaf
  IL_002f:  dup
  IL_0030:  ldfld      class [mscorlib]System.Action ConsoleTests.Program6/Leaf::OnTrigger
  IL_0035:  ldloc.0
  IL_0036:  ldfld      class [mscorlib]System.Action ConsoleTests.Program6/Chunk::OnTrigger
  IL_003b:  call       class [mscorlib]System.Delegate [mscorlib]System.Delegate::Combine(class [mscorlib]System.Delegate,
                                                                                          class [mscorlib]System.Delegate)
  IL_0040:  castclass  [mscorlib]System.Action
  IL_0045:  stfld      class [mscorlib]System.Action ConsoleTests.Program6/Leaf::OnTrigger
  IL_004a:  ldloc.0
  IL_004b:  dup
  IL_004c:  ldfld      class [mscorlib]System.Action ConsoleTests.Program6/Chunk::OnTrigger
  IL_0051:  ldnull
  IL_0052:  ldftn      void ConsoleTests.Program6::World()
  IL_0058:  newobj     instance void [mscorlib]System.Action::.ctor(object,
                                                                    native int)
  IL_005d:  call       class [mscorlib]System.Delegate [mscorlib]System.Delegate::Combine(class [mscorlib]System.Delegate,
                                                                                          class [mscorlib]System.Delegate)
  IL_0062:  castclass  [mscorlib]System.Action
  IL_0067:  stfld      class [mscorlib]System.Action ConsoleTests.Program6/Chunk::OnTrigger
  IL_006c:  ldloc.0
  IL_006d:  ldfld      class ConsoleTests.Program6/Leaf ConsoleTests.Program6/Chunk::leaf
  IL_0072:  callvirt   instance void ConsoleTests.Program6/Leaf::Go()
```

Notice that when you do a `+=` on a delegate, the compiler converts that into a `Combine` call, which combines the current delegate with the passed in one. Now look at IL_004b, which is a `dup` call.

> From the MSDN: *"Copies the current topmost value on the evaluation stack, and then pushes the copy onto the evaluation stack."*

This tells the runtime to duplicate the object on the stack, and since this is `ICloneable`, it creates a *copy* of the object. Now when you add another delegate to it, you are not adding it to both, just the one you are operating on, leaving the `Leaf` trigger as it was.

The *almost* equivalent code is this:

```
public Tree()
{
    var chunk2 = new Chunk();
    chunk2.OnTrigger += Hello; // OK: will be called
    chunk2.leaf.OnTrigger = (Action)chunk2.OnTrigger.Clone();
    chunk2.OnTrigger += World; // NOT: not be called
    chunk2.leaf.Go();
}
```

Which may make it a little clearer about what is going on here.

Comment: thanks Ron. I tried to implement a cascaded event. I didnt know it would clone and merge the original list. I thought it would point to the a delegate that then would call it's functions...

Comment: i had to implement a intermediary function `void _OnTrigger(){if (OnTrigger != null) OnTrigger();}` in order to create this cascading effect. Ugly and super tedious.

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with the order per se.

It has everything to do with the assignments you've made.

```
    chunk2.OnTrigger += Hello; // this is **never** called
    chunk2.leaf.OnTrigger += chunk2.OnTrigger; // this is the only one called
    chunk2.OnTrigger += World; // this is **never** called
```

When you call `chunk2.leaf.Go();` the only event that fires is `chunk2.leaf.OnTrigger`. The `chunk2.OnTrigger` is never called.

Comment: I think the confusion is that the OP assumes that because `Action` is a reference type, once you set the reference any action on the original will affect all of them, I think I cleared up why that isn't the case in my answer.